# Formatting hyperlink as a picture in a custom list schema

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss, wss-3.0

In my custom list XML I added a few URL fields. one of them has to be displayed as a picture just like when you select "Format URL as: Picture" in the fields settings of the UI.

In the customList's schema.xml I haven't found any place where to override the html markup for a URL type.

Any help or clue is welcome :) 
Thanks,

teebot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the Format property of the relevant fields xml Schema.
Get a copy of [SharePoint Manager](http://www.codeplex.com/spm) to try it.

```
<Field ID="{c29e077d-f466-4d8e-8bbe-72b66c5f205c}" Name="URL"
SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="URL" 
Group="Base Columns" Type="URL" DisplayName="URL" ColName="nvarchar3" 
RowOrdinal="0" ColName2="nvarchar4" RowOrdinal2="0" Format="Image" Version="1" />
```

Comment: Thanks Nat! just before reading your post I made a windiff between a generated list and mine and eventually found out the Format="Image".